# Converting a Excel function to be dynamic

Tags: excel, vba, xls

I have a XLS file which is basically a summary of three other XLS files which contains data based upon people and dates, productivity worksheets.

The cell G$2 contains the date for the summary, which is matched against the first column of the other XLS files, defined by the sheet labelled "PersonA". It then returns a value based upon the number of hours worked for that particular person.

As you can imagine, it is difficult to maintain when people leave and join the business.

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        'D:\Folder1\FolderA\[File-1.xlsm]PersonA'!$A:$Q,
        MATCH(
            G$2,
            'D:\Folder1\FolderA\[File-1.xlsm]PersonA'!$A:$A,
            0
        ),
        3
    ),
"")
```

Now the summary XLS has the persons name contained and the filename can be derived from another cell within the summary XLS, so it would be great if I could replace the hardcoded file and persons name with the contents of a cell.

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work, probably due to INDIRECT not being able to be used to construct a workbook as such.

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        INDIRECT("D:\Folder1\FolderA\["&$A$4&".xlsm]"&A5&"!$A:$Q"),
        MATCH(
            G$2,
            INDIRECT("D:\Folder1\FolderA\["&$A$4&".xlsm]"&A5&"!$A:$A"),
            0
        ),
        3
    ),
"")
```

I've considered passing such parameters into a VBA function, but came unstuck with that as well, I couldn't get the "Application.Worksheet.Index" function to work at all.

Any help would be gladfully received.

Comment: I think you're missing then `'`s

Comment: To debug this I would make a cell with `"D:\Folder1\FolderA\["&$A$4&".xlsm]"&A5&"!$A:$Q"` as its formula and check the contents, then use that in the INDIRECT and adjust until that works, then proceed with the full formula.

Comment: The single quotes didn't work, before the first D:\ and either at the end after the !$A:$A or just before it.

Comment: I think the issue is with INDIRECT not being able to open a closed workbook, or get values from another workbook. I have read about a PULL function which has been used by people in the past to overcome this INDIRECT limitation.